# WSO2 Greg Clustering Hardware LoadBalancer

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

We are planning to try out WSO2 Greg and wanted to know if we use external hardware load balancer, do we still need to configure manager + worker node configuration or we can start two standalone instances connecting to same back end i.e. oracle database and load balance it via front end external load balancer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a third-party load balancer for WSO2 GREG cluster. You do not have to use manager/worker configuration for Axis2 clustering (subDomain property) as we use with WSO2 ELB.

You will still have to configure Axis2 clustering without subDomain property. I would recommend you to use wka membership scheme and nominate few nodes as wka members in the cluster.

Comment: ok, so only Axis2 configuration with wka & members but skip the elastic load balancer, which will replaced by hardware loadbalancer. My next follow up question was, why do we need localmemberport to be different on both nodes? We can bing to same port number as the nodes are different for the members right? Trying to minimize number of different ports used to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes. You can use the same localMemberPort as long as the port number is free.

Comment: Great! I'm happy to answer! You can try this out and check whether the nodes join properly. Normally you should see join messages sent by nodes on the wso2carbon.log of well-known member. One more tip, if you are using latest products on Carbon 4.2.0, i.e. GREG 4.6.0, you should use IPs for localMemberHost and members. Sometimes the hostnames do not work due to underlying Hazelcast issue.